# access by link in bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have private repository in bitbucket. Can I make something similar as *Anyone with a link to the file* can to share in Google Drive? I want to make my repository private, but so that some people (I do not know the specific accounts of these people) could read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add users with read access](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/grant-users-and-groups-access-243335345.html), but that would be for the all repo.

That is the problem with Git: you either can read the full repo (needed to clone it) or you cannot read it at all.
There is no "file-level".

You would need to synchronize your file to a service which has a shared-link feature (like for instance a Google Drive, or Dropbox, or ...)

> I don't want to file-level access.
>   I want to give access to FULL repo to all users who has link on this.
>   Unfortunately, I don't know these users have account BitBucket or no

Fair enough, but again, I don't know of an anonymous shared access link feature (for BitBucket or GitHub or GitLab).

One possible workaround would be setup an **[access key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-access-keys-294486051.html)**

> You can use access keys with your Bitbucket Cloud repositories. An access key grants read-only access to a public or private repository. With an access key, a user or a process can pull or clone a repository over SSH.

By communicating the private key (whose public key has been registered as an access key to your private repo), you would effectively grant read access to that repo to anyone with that private key.

Comment: I don't want to file-level acess. I want to give acess to FULL repo to all users who has link on this. Unfortunatelly, I don't know these users have account bitbucket or not and I don't know their Bitbucket account name. I want to show only them my account (give link) but I don't want to all users can read it.

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev OK. I have edited the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: but setup SSH keys give opportunity for read access only for people who have BitBucket account ?  Function of Google Drive to share with "Anyone with a link" is absolutely everyone to read without any problems

Comment: Or the person who gets my key may not even be able to use SSH. I was hoping that there is an easy way to show my code to a certain group of people, but without creating problems for them to view, and so that outsiders do not look at this code

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev no need for a bitbucket account: through ssh, the access key is identification enough. Outsider (without the key) won't be able to access the same repo

Comment: okay If I generated SSH keys, How can I integrate ssh authentication through a URL? And can I do it? To make it easier to see my repository?

Comment: in Google I get a link URL which I give to a friend or group of people and they read at my file, despite the fact that he has an google account or not. How to do it in bitbaket after I generated SSH?

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev Let me be clearer: I am not aware, as I clearly state in my answer, of a "link" which would give instant access. Hence my edited solution where I propose a *workaround* (not an exact solution as the one you are looking for, but something which would still achieve the general result you are after).

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev Simply communicate the private key, and anyone can do an `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i private_key git clone git@bitbucket.org/you/yourrepo`

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not see the workaround that reaches my goal.  You suggested to synchronize my file to a service which has a shared-link feature (like for instance a Google Drive, or Dropbox, or ...). But I do not want to specifically see the file, but to see the commits, the changes. If I build a link to the repository in this service, I will have to make the repository open. But I want to make the repository closed.

Comment: Above I wrote that the person to whom I want to give access to reading may not be able to use the git and do not know these commands. I do not want him to apply the instruction and complicate access to reading. The user wants to see at what stage of the project - how much code is written, how often commits go. Screenshots of throwing uncomfortable (because there are many) and plus a person can think that I can cheat.

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev I understand what you want, and still and didn't see any obvious solution, I was just trying to provide a practical solution. However, for adding anonymous external access, you might want to check with BitBucket support (https://bitbucket.org/support), to see if they have a more precise insight.

Comment: Well, thank you for your support. I will leave this question as it is. I did not think that only I needed such anonymous access.